# Python -Page Object-Inheritance Failed

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, inheritance, pageobjects

I am trying hard to create a Base class that inherits one from another. The goals are:

to set up one base class with the connection and driver
to make that this class automatically open the connection once for all test I run and then connection is close once test suite finished.
To put all elements locators and assertion in one place and to use these methods in all subclases. In order to achieve this, I 've create several methods but I am not understanding how inheritance works in Python 3. (it is much easier in Java I must say and I am almost giving up)

## **Config File:**:

```
url = 'http://newtours.demoaut.com/'
driver_path = '/home/osboxes/PycharmProjects/Automation/geckodriver-v0.21.0-arm7hf'
pjs_path = '/home/osboxes/PycharmProjects/Automation/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs'
firefox_binary = '/usr/bin'
```

## **Connect File :**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import Automation.config as config

class Connect():
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path= config.pjs_path)
        self.driver.get(config.url)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(20)
        return self.driver
```

## **Base Page:**

```
import unittest
from Automation.connect import Connect
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

class BasePage(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self,.setUp()):
        con = Connect()
        my_driver = con.SetUp()

def is_element_present(how,what):
    try:
        element = (how, what)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True
```

**HomeTest**

```
from  Automation import basePage as bp
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from Automation.connect import Connect
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from Automation.basePage import BasePage as bp
import unittest

class HomeTest(bp):
    def __init__(self):
        super.__init__()

    def test_home(self):
        self.home = HomeTest()
        self.user = self.home.my_driver.find_element(bp.is_element_present(By.NAME, "username"))
```

## **Response:**

```
/home/osboxes/PycharmProjects/Automation/venv/bin/python /home/osboxes/PycharmProjects/Automation/Automation/home_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/osboxes/PycharmProjects/Automation/Automation/home_test.py", line 40, in <module>
    unittest.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/main.py", line 141, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/main.py", line 145, in createTests
    self.test = self.testLoader.loadTestsFromModule(self.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 123, in loadTestsFromModule
    tests.append(self.loadTestsFromTestCase(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 92, in loadTestsFromTestCase
    loaded_suite = self.suiteClass(map(testCaseClass, testCaseNames))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/suite.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.addTests(tests)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/suite.py", line 57, in addTests
    for test in tests:
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

**I've tried to put connect setting as keyword arguments on __init__ method but it doesn't work. in my case I want to set up a global behavior for all subclasses by defect. I want that all subclasses use the driver by inherit from one class.**